# Can I send an email with a predefined reply message

Tags: email

I use the Contact Form 7 Plugin for wordpress and have it configured to send from my local email to the admin with the reply-to set to the customers email. This works great in gmail, I can reply to the form submission like any other email and keep the conversation organized.

To take it a step further I wanted to know if it was possible to set a default reply message. So when I hit reply the message would be pre-populated with a personalized canned response. If theres a way specific to google that would be fine.

I know I could do a mailto link that pre-populates the message body but I was hoping for a slightly more "integrated" function, so to speak.

Comment: Well, I played with genaric mailto links in the message body. If I make the subject match the original I think google will keep them together. I also tried including the responses in the original message. If you highlight the text in gmail and click reply it fills with the selected text. What I was hoping might exist is a header that I could pass along that would use googles built in canned response or just redefine the reply text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to not be any method for this. I ended up sticking with including canned responses with the message. Highlighting the text and pressing reply populates the reply with the highlighted text.